# Are there infinitely many different primes of the form $\sigma(n^2)-\varphi(n)\sigma(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum

While I was trying to create a problem using the sum of divisors function $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$$ and the Euler's totient function $\varphi(n)$ from this pattern $$\sigma(\text{a positive integer})-\sigma(\text{a different  integer})\cdot\varphi(\text{a different integer})=\text{something},$$ I wondered next question.

> **Question.** Are there infinitely many different primes solving the RHS as   $$\sigma(n^2)-\varphi(n)\sigma(n)=\text{a prime number}\tag{1}$$ when $n$ runs over the positive integers $\geq 1$?

**Example 1.** For $n=4$ one has that $$\sigma(16)-\varphi(4)\cdot\sigma(4)=31-2\cdot7=17=\text{ a prime number solving the RHS of our equation}.$$

**Example 2.** See with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) codes for different upper limits

`table IsPrime(sigma(n^2)-sigma(n)*phi(n)), for n=1 to 5000`

`table sigma(n^2)-sigma(n)*phi(n), for n=1 to 1000`

Thus our sequence of prime numbers solving the RHS for some integer $n$ of our condition $(1)$ starts (as I said we ommit repetead primes) as $$5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19\ldots$$

---

I don't know if this question was in the literature I tried find strings like as  *sigma(n^2)-sigma(n)* or *sigma(n^2)-sigma(n)* in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/). Of course, if you can identify our sequence and if previous Question was in the literature refers it, and I try find the information.

Then, from this information what are you saying? **Many thanks.**

Comment: One can to study for the cases (maybe this can be rule out easily) $\gcd(p,n)=1$, where $p$ is $\text{ the prime number}$ solving $(1)$. Multiplying $(1)$ by this prime, one has  $p\sigma(n^2)-p\varphi(n)\sigma(n)=(\sigma(n^2)-\varphi(n)\sigma(n))^2$ (or if you prefer multiply by a prime power to improve my approach). Then *the strategy is rewrite* in LHS terms as (the first term of LHS can be written as) $(p+1-1)\sigma(n^2)-\sigma(pn^2)$, *and try to apply knowledges about the size of those arithmetic functions* (for example one has for $n>1$ that $\sigma(n^2)\geq 1+(\sigma(n)-1)+n^2$).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Mistake spotted, the answer was changed.

Let us look at the case $n=p^k$. 
We have
$$\sigma(p^{2k})-\phi(p^k)\sigma(p^k)=1+p+p^2+..+p^{2k}-(p^{k-1})(p-1)(1+p+...+p^{k})\\
=1+p+p^2+..+p^{2k}-(p^{k-1})(p^{k+1}-1)\\
=1+p+p^2+...+p^{k-1}+p^{k+1}+p^{2k-1}=\frac{p^{2k}-1}{p-1}-p^k$$

In general it is hard to decide if there are infinitely many primes of a certain form. If $k=1$, your question becomes equivalent to the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: Many thanks for your reasoning.